# How to use .endswith in Python to omit file extension?

Tags: python

I have an ArcPy script for ArcGIS Desktop 10 where I am executing several functions. One of the functions copies all layers that are associated with a Map Document to a database.  I would like to copy all files except files that end with `.sid`.

Here is a snippet of my code.  I do not want`.sid` extensions in either of the `datasetName` or `dataSource` variables.  How can I make the below more Pythonic so that I do not include `.sid` files.

```
   for lyr in lyrList:
                    lyrName = lyr.name
                    SidData = " "
                    SidDataName= " "
                    if lyr.supports("dataSource"):
                        lyrDatasource = lyr.dataSource
                        lyrDataSetName = lyr.datasetName
                    if lyrDatasource.endswith(".sid"):
                        lyrDatasource == SidData
                    else:
                        pass

                    if lyrDataSetName.endswith(".sid"):
                        lyrDataSetName == SidDataName
                    else:
                        pass
```

Comment: Your code is very confused. `lyrDatasource == SidData` doesn't do anything. `pass` doesn't do anything. So both your `if lyrDataSetName.endswith(".sid")` statements are not doing anything. I can't tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: I see, I am trying to omit any file from lyDatasource and lyrDataSetName that ends with .sid

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a trivial question or I am missing something. You can simply use the `not` keyword.

```
>>> foo = "file.sid"
>>> foo.endswith('.sid')
True
>>> not foo.endswith('sid')
False
```

So it would be something like:

```
if not datasetName.endswith('.sid'):
    # Execute only if the file does NOT end with '.sid'
else:
    # Execute if file ends with '.sid'
```